# What does "it should be" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Mank* (2020), writer Mank was on the bed with scripts. Rita let the mover
bring Mank's support device in and place it in the corner:

> Mank: Enough room there?
>
> Mover: Oh, **it should be**.

What does "it should be" mean?

Comment: He doesn't say '**it** should be'. He just says 'Ahh, should be'. The online script references are wrong. I found a clip of just those two sentences [oddly] - https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/67650851-8ec4-4f37-ab89-681e794fe1bf Even the clip is wrongly titled 'it should be'.

Comment: Subtitles are not always accurate

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am not only looking at subs but also listening to the words speaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

Here "it should be" means "I'm pretty sure it will be, but I won't know for certain until I actually put it where it belongs."  Unless it's being said sarcastically in which case it could mean either "there is not any possibility of it fitting" or "it will fit easily, why are you even asking?"

Comment: The line quoted is wrong. Did you check it before answering? No-one would respond 'it should be'

Comment: "It should be enough" is fairly idiomatic, and "It should be" is a reasonable shortened form.

Comment: '**There** should be' would be an idiomatic response to the question as asked by Mank. We're trying to explain a typo/misquote, which is never a good thing.

Comment: " No-one would respond 'it should be'" I would, although I'd be more likely to say, "It ought to." Six of one, half a dozen of the other. I disagree with your assessment.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - you'd respond to "Is there enough room there?" "It ought to"… really? Apart from anything else, the mover did not even say "**it** should be" he just said "err, should be". Had this answer been properly checked against the movie dialog, this entire discussion needn't have happened. I spend more time on movies.se than here, where a mondegreen or 'misheard lyric' often just gets closed.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - Doesn't matter if the line got misquoted.. Either way it means the same thing, and gets the same answer. I really don't see the basis for your objection.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - it **does** matter that the line is misquoted. It makes this answer complete nonsense, & your "it ought to" is even wider of the mark. The question should just have been closed… or at least checked before answering blind.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. OK, you've never given the basis for your (obviously strongly-held) objection. So please inform us - exactly what do "Ahhh, should be." and "It should be" mean, and what exactly the differences are?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - One is what he said. The other isn't. "It should be" is simply not the right answer to the question Mank asked. No-one would say that. That's it's not what was actually said anyway just invalidates the entire question. tbh, I'm more at odds with your alternative, "it ought to", which you seem to be ignoring.